# Using mathlink/WSTP with fortran

Tags: programming, mathlink-or-wstp

I would like to access Mathematica functions from within a Fortran program. I am unsure how to start (which is probably related to my lack of up-to-date Fortran knowledge). Is it necessary to write a wrapper in C or can I link to the Mathematica library directly. Are there any Fortan examples available which I could start from? How would I compile the Fortran project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

- You can write a C wrapper function that calls your Fortran code, and use WSTP to export the C function to Mathematica.

  It is relatively straightforward to mix Fortran and C. [gfortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran) is one free compiler. The procedure for linking the compiled C and Fortran object files will depend on your platform, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135296/call-c-c-code-form-a-fortran-program-in-visual-studio-how-to-compile-mixed-c).
- If your code is Fortran 77, you can use [f2c](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/) to convert it into ANSI C, and then use WSTP on the C code directly.